# Plotting multiple X,Y signals into single XYGraph matlab stateflow

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

i have two signals coming from my model as output each of which contain x,y values. i want to plot both of them on single xy graph window. i am able to draw it on two xy graph window but how to merge them and draw on same xy window?

Comment: +1 Looking for the same thing — you should be able to mux all X signals, and mux all Y signals. SHOULD. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do what you want. The best alternative would be to log the data to the workspace and plot it as you want after the simulation has finished, using standard MATLAB commands.

Comment: but i want to plot the graph while simulation is running

Comment: Like I said, I don't think you can do what you want easily. You'll have to use 2 different X-Y Scope blocks. It may be possible to do something custom with a MATLAB Function block, but I'm not sure how to go about it (you'll have to hold the plot and redraw it at each time step somehow).

Answer (score 0):

by using XY scope , Plots second input (Y) against first input (X) at each time step to  create an X-Y plot